# Why is this SQL returning "Invalid Number" when I convert VARCHAR2 to an INTEGER?

Tags: oracle11g

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT C1,CAST(C1 as NUMBER) FROM my_materialized_view WHERE C1 IS NOT NULL AND C1 != '0'
```

C1 is a VARCHAR2 column that contains nulls and 0 values. Those are filtered out in the WHERE clause. This query works if I `SELECT C1 FROM` - remove the CAST() - from the statement.

When I run the above SQL in its entirety, I get `ORA-01722: invalid number`.

How should I convert a column in the materialized view to a number so I can perform calculations?

UPDATE - I also tried `select cast(c1 as integer)` as suggested in comments. It returns the same error.

UPDATE - I ran this `select C1 from my_materialized_view where C1 IS NOT NULL and C1 != '0' order by C1` and did not find any values outside the range of 1001000 to 999300. Seems like a valid test.

Comment: what about `select cast(c1 as integer)` ?

Comment: Are you sure there are only numbers in that column?

Comment: Is `C1` only returning values that contain numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that some values in `C1` column are not numeric strings.  You cannot cast a string like `'1 0'` (with space in between) into number for example.

Try using `SELECT C1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(C1) = 0` to determine where the problematic value is.

For Oracle:
http://odiexperts.com/is_number-at-oracle-a-work-around/

Comment: There was a row that contained two integer values separated by a slash.